# Two statement in one function was called different times in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react to create an app. I used create-react-app to setup the project. The following code was used to render the content.

```
renderVideoShowBlock = () => {
    if (this.state.videoRecords) {
        return this.state.videoRecords.map((record) => {
            console.log("renderVideoShowBlock called", record.id)
            return (
                <VideoShowBlock
                    user={this.state.user}
                    key={record.id}
                    record={record}
                    onItemDelete={() => {this.handleVideoItemDelete(record.id)}}
                />
            )
        })
    }
}
```

the function `this.handleVideoItemDelete` will make an axios post request to "video/". I find that when this `onItemDelete` is called in inner modules, the record in closure is always point to the last record in `this.state.videoRecords`. I use the folowing code to track what happend:

```
render() {
    const videoJsOptions = this.videoJsOptions
    const contentBlock = (
        <div className='video-box col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10 col-12
                            offset-lg-3 offset-md-2 offset-sm-1' >
            <VideoPlayer {...videoJsOptions} />
        </div>
    )

    console.log("VideoShowBlock render called")
    this.props.onItemDelete()
    return (
        <ShowBlock user={this.props.user}
                   author={this.props.record.author}
                   content={contentBlock}
                   onItemDelete={this.props.onItemDelete}
        />
    )
}
```

We can see that

```
console.log("VideoShowBlock render called")
this.props.onItemDelete()
```

was called sequently. In chrome console, we find:
[console.log was called 3 times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYoNX.png)
but in network tab, we find [this.props.onItemDelete was called 6 times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzpvB.png), each video record's `onItemDelete` was called two times.

If I comment `this.props.onItemDelete`, there will be no request being sent, which means I can not see any request in network tab. It seems like the function was called twice.
Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you are calling `this.props.onItemDelete()`

and you are also passing it in the ShowBlock component what does it do?

```
 return (
        <ShowBlock user={this.props.user}
                   author={this.props.record.author}
                   content={contentBlock}
                   onItemDelete={this.props.onItemDelete} // here
        />
    )
```

Maybe you are also calling it in the `<ShowBlock/>` component that's why the request was sent two times.

Comment: That was why it's wierd. If I comment ```this.props.onItemDelete()```, there will be no request being sent.

Comment: so are you using the onItemDelete()  inside the show block component?

Comment: Yes, I use it by ```onClick={this.onItemDelete}```, passing it to a button.